# dotenv error! trying to use dotenv, but receiving errors about several 'missing modules'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, dotenv

I need to use environmental factors for a react project, but whenever I try to use dotenv, I receive A BUNCH of 'module not found' errors. I even tried to install every module that is mentioned in these errors, but it doesn't matter. I still get the same damn errors, it's frustrating. I've tried uninstalling & reinstalling dotenv, and I've tried installing every so-called 'missing model' but it doesn't matter, I still get the same damn errors when I use this line in my code "require('dotenv').config();". I don't know why it's so complicated to run & why there are so many dependencies, it makes me feel extremely inadequate as a programmer :(

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js 1:11-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/tazar/nft-minter-tutorial-idk/minter-starter-files/node_modules/dotenv/lib'
 @ ./src/util/pinata.js 3:0-24
 @ ./src/util/stopbeingadick.js 4:0-44
 @ ./src/Minter.js 8:0-81 58:14-39 65:33-46
 @ ./src/App.js 5:0-30 11:35-41
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 11:33-36

ERROR in ./node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js 3:13-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/tazar/nft-minter-tutorial-idk/minter-starter-files/node_modules/dotenv/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
 @ ./src/util/pinata.js 3:0-24
 @ ./src/util/stopbeingadick.js 4:0-44
 @ ./src/Minter.js 8:0-81 58:14-39 65:33-46
 @ ./src/App.js 5:0-30 11:35-41
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 11:33-36

ERROR in ./node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js 5:11-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in '/Users/tazar/nft-minter-tutorial-idk/minter-starter-files/node_modules/dotenv/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") }'
    - install 'os-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "os": false }
 @ ./src/util/pinata.js 3:0-24
 @ ./src/util/stopbeingadick.js 4:0-44
 @ ./src/Minter.js 8:0-81 58:14-39 65:33-46
 @ ./src/App.js 5:0-30 11:35-41
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 11:33-36

3 errors have detailed information that is not shown.
Use 'stats.errorDetails: true' resp. '--stats-error-details' to show it.

webpack 5.69.1 compiled with 3 errors and 1 warning in 21 ms
```

Comment: The error tells you exactly what you need to do. You need to install the pollyfills it says. `npm i path-browserify` and `npm i os-browserify`

Comment: didn't make a difference at all, still get the exact same error message